# A geometric approach to this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

Question:

A function $f$ is defined on the complex numbers by $f(z)=(a+bi)z$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers. This function has the property that the image of each point in the complex plane is equidistant from that point and the origin. Given that $|a+bi|=8$, find the value of $b^2$.

I have already solved the problem algebraically; however, the book asks for a geometric approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regard a complex number $z$ as $x+iy$  representing the point $x\choose y$ in the plane. Then $f(z)= (a+ib)z$ corresponds to matrix multiplication  by $\pmatrix{a & -b\cr b & a}$  (verify this!).  Dividing all entries of this matrix by $8$ calling the corresponding function $g(z)$ we can see that $f(z)= 8g(z)$.  Now $g(z)$ corresponds to rotation of the plane. (Try to find out by what angle. Take a point before and after applying $g(z)$ to find the angle).

So geometrically $f(z)$ is a rotation followed by stretching (scaling) by 8.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that the problem tells us is that this function exists, and has the same special property for **any** $z$.

So let's pick any random $z$. I'm going to pick $2$ because it is easy to work with. Since $f(2)$ must be equidistant from $0$ and $2$, it must be on the line $\Im(z)=1$. Since $|a+bi|=8$, we know that $f(2)$ is also on the circle $|z|=2\cdot8$.

So, we get that $\displaystyle f(z)=16e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(16\right)}$ or $\displaystyle f(z)=16e^{i\left(2\pi-\tan^{-1}\left(16\right)\right)}$.

From this, we know that $a+bi=f\displaystyle(z)=8e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(16\right)}$ or $a+bi=8e^{i\left(2\pi-\tan^{-1}\left(16\right)\right)}$.

Either way, $\displaystyle b^2=\left(8\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(16\right)\right)\right)^2=\frac{255}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric solution.

$f(1)=a+bi$ has the same distance to both (0,0) and (1,0). Then $f(1)=a+bi$ must lie on the line x=0.5: the line across the mid-point between (0,0) and (1,0) and orthogonal to the straight line connecting (0,0) and (1,0).

Now consider the triangle of the three points: (0,0), (0.5,0) and (a,b).
The angle at (0.5,0) is 90 degree, and the length from (0,0) to (a,b) is 8. $|b|$ is the length from (0.5,0) to (a,b).
Then we have $a^2 + b^2 = 8^2$ => $b^2=64-0.25$. We also have $a=0.5$.